# How can i change JSON structure by group variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, algorithm

I'm trying to change JSON structure for push to my database

**my old JSON :**

```
       [
          {"name": "nameGallery"},
          {"img": "1.jpg"},
          {"img": "2.img"}
       ]
```

**And I want to group "img" variable to "Images" Array like this:**

```
[
  {
    "name": "nameGallery",
    "Images": [
              {"img": "1.jpg"},
              {"img": "2.img"}
              ]
  }
]
```

**I'm trying to use object.assign to manage it but I don't know why it error.**

```
function getData() {
    fetch('text/upload.json').then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        data = data.map(o => Object.assign({}, o,
        { Images: o.Images.map(({ img }) => ({ img: img })) }
        ));
    })
}
```

My Result:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure data has a value? What is console.log(data) showing?

Comment: @basic it's probably `o.Images` that's `undefined`.

Comment: That's because there is not property called Images in the o object.

Comment: Another problem in that you need to show a more realistic data sample that can help someone provide you with a better answer. Can you show the original JSON with more information in the array than just what you have here?

Comment: @asiby Thank you,next time,I'll care more about realistic data sample.

Comment: It's alright. I am glad you have found the solution you needed. That's all that matters at the end of the day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your solution you are calling `.map` which will create you one array entry for every array entry in your initial data.

As you described, you expect one object as a result and not an array of object. So look at the following :

```js
const data = [{
    name: 'nameGallery',
  },
  {
    img: '1.jpg',
  },
  {
    img: '2.img',
  },
];

// You want to create a new object using all the others objects
const ret = data.reduce((tmp, x) => {
  // If the key below is 'img', we push the object into 'Images'
  // void 0 means undefined
  if (x.img !== void 0) {
    tmp.Images.push(x);

    return tmp;
  }

  // If the key is not 'img'
  // We copy the keys into tmp
  return {
    ...tmp,

    ...x,
  };
}, {
  // initialize 'Images' key here it won't be undefined
  // when pushing the first data
  Images: [],
});

console.log(ret);
```

Comment: Thank you very much,I got it : )

Answer (score -2):

You can try something like this:

```
function getData() {
    fetch('text/upload.json').then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        const name = data.find(o => !!o.name);

        return {
          name: name.name,
          Images: data.filter(o => !!o.img)
        };
    })
}
```